# Disable logging in libvlc api

Tags: libvlc

I get log warning - "deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly" in console. How disable this log from console ? I often turn the player on and off and these logs trash the output.

Comment: Have you tried `--quiet`?

Comment: i use libvlc and I don't know how used parameters for running

Comment: you need to provide more information, such as your code